# Background images and background attachment

Tags: html, css, background-attachment

I'm having trouble with adding backgrounds to different elements on the same page and could use some help. I'm trying to make a one page site with multiple sections and backgrounds (like http://ofarevolution.com/) using "background-attachment" but I can't get more than one background to appear. I'm going insane, please help.

Here is my setup: http://codepen.io/marks828/pen/YWLKmw

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="stage">
        <p>
            "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="fraknie">
    <div>
        <p>
            "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>



.stage{
background-image: url("../img/portfolio/stage.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.frankie {

background-image: url("../img/portfolio/frankie.jpg");
}
```

Comment: there is a typo in class name frankie(CSS) vs fraknie(HTML)

Answer (score 0):

is the code `<div class="fraknie">` supposed to be "fraknie"?

Comment: I'm going to go jump off a bridge now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The proble is the type in class name

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="stage">
            <p>
                "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="frankie">
        <div>
        <p>
            "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

[Here the corrected code working](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/nws8ae0y/)

Comment: Ugh. Nothing makes me feel dumber than missing something that obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @mark-sweet worst problem to found, you can watch to the code for hours without see the typo ;)